# iOS: MKMapView loads very slowly with debug configuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, configuration, mkmapview

So I have a project with an MKMapView in it. The problem is that whenever, or wherever in my project I init an MKMapView it will hang the whole app for about 10-15 seconds.

I triple checked everything, **the problem is not** networking on the main thread, or too many annotation views or anything like it and it also happens if I don't add the mapview, only init it.

The weird thing is that this seem to be only happening if I build the app from xcode. **If I archive the app and install it, the map loads quickly.**

This has lead me to believe that **there could be a misconfiguration** somewhere in the debug configuration or project settigns but after checking the scheme settings I came up empty.

Do you guys have a suggesting about what could cause such a behavior?

Comment: are you installing it with development profile

Comment: yes, would the lack of a valid profile cause something like this?

Comment: i have the same, since I updated my Iphone with ios6. Have you solved it?

Comment: I have the project in a git repo. If I delete the working copy and checkout the repo (with no changes made, so the wc and the repo have the same code) it will work normally for some time, but will revert back to this behaviour eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem:
I solved it by deleting all breakpoints (event the inactive ones)
In Xcode open the Breakpoints tab sheet, and select "delete breakpoints"

Comment: Nice find! That is the solution.

Comment: But it is still strange, after two new breakpoints the same happened again.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot get my head around it either. And it's not every time this happens. I'm curious whether XCode 5 has this issues as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having the same problem. Funny thing is you couldn't even stop the app during this delay. Xcode itself seems to stall and wait for the app to finally get around to continuing.

Answer (score 0):

no if you use development profile it takes time to load because it will load all ur breakpoints also so ders nothing to worry and if you use your provisioning profile it will work fast (or) if you archive it it will work fast.

Comment: i have no breakpoints, and the issue is only with the mapview. Also, if I import every class to another, fresh project and build it there are no problems, the map loads quickly.

Comment: plus 10-15 seconds of initialization delay wouldn't be acceptable anyway for any reasons in development

Comment: thats ok if no breakpoints but it loads your directions and many other things with your map and ders will be services running with your map so it will take tym

Comment: I have not encountered this behavior in any of my past projects and as I say, importing all the classes to another project solves the issue, so there should be something with either project settings, scheme settings, build settings or build configuration I just currently have no idea what.